# Laravel 4.2 compatibility with MariaDB 10.2

Tags: laravel-4, mariadb

I have a Laravel 4.2.2 app that I have invested a lot of time in building and is currently live in production. According to the Laravel documentation, version 4.2 is compatible with "PHP version 5.4 or greater." But I know that although the app runs on PHP 5.6 and 7.0, it won't run on PHP 7.1 or higher.

I can't find similar documentation for Laravel 4.2 compatibility with MySQL versions (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database). I am currently on MySQL version 5.6 (at end of life). My hosted server uses cPanel and allows me to run the app in older PHP version, but if I upgrade from MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.2, there is no downgrade or backward compatible mode. I'd hate to be in a situation where the app stops working and there is no fix.

Does anyone have experience with Laravel 4.2 on MariaDB 10.2. If there are compatibility issues, is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: *" I'd hate to be in a situation where the app stops working and there is no fix."* Do you get a error/stacktrace?

Comment: Raymond, no error since I haven't upgraded yet. But the upgrade on WHM is irreversable. Hence the wisdom of checking first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Laravel 4.2 application works with no issues whatsoever on MariaDB 10.2.